# dodirect payment using paypal pro in php

Tags: php, paypal

I am doing a NVP for a doDirectPayment.

I am getting error response 10001 as below.

Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-02-26T10:52:52Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 7870481221c21
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 9878152
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 12.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)

Some time its works but most of the time I am getting above response.

Can you please suggest some solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting that on the sandbox or on the live server?  Do you have a sample of the API request that you sent with this error occurred?  It could be an issue with PayPal's servers, but it could also be a problem with your request, so this particular error can be tough to troubleshoot.  In most cases it's a problem with your request when it continues to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting this at sandbox not at live.

Comment: And can you post a sample of the request that's getting sent when it happens?

Answer (score 0):

If this is on sandbox then this is just sandbox error. I didn't have any internal error on live server. On sandbox I have a lot of them. Sandbox just dies sometimes probably.